# How to package a Activity into jar file in Android?

Tags: android

I want to make an interface of Activity so that other peolpe can use it ,My activit calls XML file which contain image source.I don't know how to package this Activity into jar file?thank you.

Comment: you can define your project as library project in your project properties.

Comment: I'm learning the library project

Comment: @rajpara Nope,the library projects cannot include raw assets

Comment: You act as though you have a choice. Right now, you do not. Either use an Android library project (and convert your assets to raw resources), or do not distribute your activity.